# Prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(YX^2-Y)$ containing $(Y-4+(YX^2-Y))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ and $S=(YX^2-Y)$.

**Question:**

a) Show that the ideal $I$ generated by $Y-4$ in $R/S$ is not prime.

b) Find complete list of prime ideals of $R/S$ containing $I$.

c) Which one of the ideals found in (b) are maximal?

**Answer:**

For part (a), I showed that as $(Y-4)(X^2-1)=YX^2-Y-4X^2+4=4-4X^2$ in $R/S$, $Y-4$ divides $4(1-X)(1+X)$ but it cannot divide any of those factors. Thus, $Y-4$ is not prime, whence $I$ is not a prime ideal.

For part (b) and (c), prime ideals of $R/S$ containing $I$ are in one to one correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ containing $YX^2-Y$ and $Y-4$. Let $P$ be such a prime ideal of  $R$. Then by $P$ being prime, it has to contain at least one of the factors of $YX^2-Y$. Thus, we have the following options. $P$ contains either the ideal
$$(Y-4,X-1),\quad (Y-4,X+1),\quad (Y,Y-4), \quad (Y-4,Y,X+1), \quad (Y-4,Y,X-1), \quad (Y-4,X+1,X-1), \quad \text{or} \quad (Y-4,Y,X-1,X+1).$$

Now I know that if $P$ contains $(X,Y)$, then $P=R$ but for the other options I don't know what to do. Also, if you spot any mistake on my answer up to this point, please let me know. Thanks in advance...

Comment: $Y-4$ belongs to any prime ideal, so you get $(Y-4,Y)$ (which is not prime), $(Y-4,X-1)$ and $(Y-4,X+1)$.

Comment: Yes you are right about the containment of $Y-4$; I corrected my mistake. But how about the other ideals I just wrote? And, why is it that $(Y-4,Y)$ is not prime? Also, can't there be a prime ideal properly containing, for instance, $(Y-4,X-1)$? More elaboration would be helpful.

Comment: $4\in(Y-4,Y)$ and $2\notin(Y-4,Y)$. The other two ideals are prime, but not maximal since their corresponding quotient rings are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: By your reasoning, I am left with the ideals $(Y-4,X+1)$, $(Y-4,X-1)$, $(Y-4,X-1,X+1)$, and $(Y-4,Y,X+1,X-1)=(Y,X+1,X-1)$. Now if I am not mistaken corresponding quotients all of those ideals are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. What I am asking is if there is a way of finding the all prime ideals containing those ideals.

Comment: Not quite! The ideal $(Y-4,X-1,p)$, with $p$ a prime number, contains $I$. This is maximal, indeed. Moreover, one can replace $p$ with any polynomial $f(X,Y)$ with $f(1,4)=p$.